# WPF приложение подключение к MSSQL

Tags: c#, wpf

С WPF я практически не знаком, однако, C# использовал для создания Xamarin приложения и , в целом, с языком знаком, однако, во время обучения встретился с проблемой подключения базы данных, созданной в SQL Server Managment Studio, к моему новенькому проекту WPF. В интернете пытался найти ответ на этот и вопрос и понял, что надо использовать Entity Framework, но понятного объяснения как именно его подключить к MSSQL и , к примеру, вывести хотя бы пару столбцов из таблицы не нашёл, ведь повсюду только гайды по SQLLite, что просто переносится полностью в проект, поэтому **прошу вас объяснить на примере как это сделать или же скинуть свежий ресурс, где это объясняется** (*к примеру, на том же metanit под эту тему подключение идёт из файла app.config, которого, как я понял, уже нет, а заменен он был на app.xaml/app.xaml.cs*)

Comment: EF один, отличия только в строке подключения и выбранном "провайдере" (dll), все... `app.config, которого, как я понял, уже нет, а заменен он был на app.xaml/app.xaml.cs` - кто вам такое сказал? Они всегда служили для разных целей, сам `app.config` вам генерирует студия в корень проекта, можете править его, ну а если нужно изменить то, что генерит - ПКМ - Добавить - Файл конфигурации (или как-то так). Так что, в интернете почти все инструкции актуальны и в чем у вас проблема возникла я не пойму... Не уж то нельзя попробовать одну из инструкций?

Comment: EF один, но почему-то на разных сайтах разные варианты подключения к одной и той же бд. Хорошо, а как мне получить доступ к app.config, если в правом окне, где показаны все файлы проекта этого App.config нет? Т.к. там только app.xaml

Comment: `разные варианты подключения` - наверно потому, что ее можно настроить на разные способы авторизации и др..? Там ведь можно и по паролю, и по домену, да куча других вариантов. `а как мне получить доступ к app.config` - читайте внимательно мой коммент выше, я ведь сказал где и как.